# WordPress Customizer API not showing Panel/Section

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm beginner in Wordpress theme development and I'm learning customizer API.
However, I'm stuck in place where I was trying to use Customizer API to change the Navigation Menu background color using WordPress Customizer but it's showing nothing despite I've included all the necessary lines according to my knowledge. Here is the code I was trying to implement inside - functions.php:

```
function textdomain_pro_theme($wp_customize) {
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'pro_features', array(
    'title' => 'Pro Features',
    'priority' => 10 
));
$wp_customize->add_section( 'color_picking' , array(
    'title' => 'Color Settings',
    'panel' => 'pro_features',
    'priority' => 30
      ));

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'nav_menu_bgcolor', array(
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'default' => '#ff2525',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    ));
$wp_customize->add_control( 'nav_menu_bgcolor', array(
    'label' => 'Navigation Bar Color',
    'type' => 'color',
    'section' => 'pro_features',
    ));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'textdomain_pro_theme' );
```

CUSTOMIZER DOESN'T SHOW THE NEW SECTION. WHAT WENT WRONG?

MY CURRENT WORDPRESS VERSION IS 6.1

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong section id in `add_control('nav_menu_bgcolor')`. replace it with `color_picking`

Try out this code if helps.

```
function textdomain_pro_theme($wp_customize) {
$wp_customize->add_panel( 'pro_features', array(
    'title' => 'Pro Features',
    'priority' => 10 
));
$wp_customize->add_section( 'color_picking' , array(
    'title' => 'Color Settings',
    'panel' => 'pro_features',
    'priority' => 30
      ));

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'nav_menu_bgcolor', array(
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'default' => '#ff2525',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
    ));
$wp_customize->add_control( 'nav_menu_bgcolor', array(
    'label' => 'Navigation Bar Color',
    'type' => 'color',
    'section' => 'color_picking',
    ));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'textdomain_pro_theme' );
```

Comment: You are right. Thank you. Also, I made one more mistake.  'type' => VALUE SHOULD BE text instead of COLOR,

Comment: I hope you resolved your issue then mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

insert the code in your function PHP file

function textdomain_pro_theme($wp_customize) {

```
$main_section_id = 'pro_features';
$wp_customize->add_section( $main_section_id, array(
    'title' => 'Color Picking',
    'priority' => 30
));

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'nav_menu_bgcolor', array(
    'type' => 'theme_mod',
    'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
    'default' => '#ff2525',
    'transport' => 'refresh',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 'nav_menu_bgcolor', array(
    'label' => 'Navigation Bar Color',
    'type' => 'color',
    'section' => $main_section_id,
));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'textdomain_pro_theme' );

// input the color in your Navigation Menu background color section
echo get_theme_mod('nav_menu_bgcolor');
```